# How can I transfer toolbar layouts between SSMS versions?

Tags: ide, ssms, toolbar

I have upgraded from SSMS 19 to 20. My keyboard shortcuts and the location of the panes (e.g. the Object Explorer) have been remembered, but the items in my toolbars and the positions of those toolbars have not. How can I transfer them?